# Conformal $L^p$ rigidity of Riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal, rigidity

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\CO}[1]{\text{CO}(#1)}$
$\newcommand{\dist}{\operatorname{dist}}$
$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$
$\newcommand{\h}{\mathfrak{h}}$
$\newcommand{\Volg}{\text{Vol}_\g}$
$\newcommand{\SO}[1]{\text{SO}(#1)}$

Let $\M,\N$ be compact oriented $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds with boundary. 
Given $x \in \M,y \in N$, we define
$$\CO{\g_x,\h_y} =\{\lambda R : R \in \SO{\g_x,\h_y} \, | \, \lambda > 0\} .$$

Consider the following functional $E:C^{\infty}(\M,\N) \to \R:$

$$E(f)= \int_\M \dist^p (df,\CO{\g,f^*h})\,\Volg, $$

which measures the deviation of $f$ from being conformal. (The distance on $\text{Hom}(T_p\M,T_{f(p)}\N)$ is the one induced by the metrics).

Define $F:=\{ f:\M \to \N \, | \,\, f \text{ is a smooth immersion}\}$.

> **Question:** Suppose $ \inf_{f \in F}E(f)=0$. Is it true that $\M$ is conformally immersible in $\N$? i.e., does there exist a smooth conformal immersion $\M \to \N$?

I assume $p >d$. (This might be necessary, for when $p < \frac{d}{2}$, then there are regularity issues, at least in the Euclidean case).

*Comment:*

The conformal group is not closed, as $0$ belongs to its closure. On manifolds, it can happen that a sequence of conformal diffeomorphisms weakly converges to a constant map (which I do not consider conformal here).

Here is a classic example: Take $\M=\N=\mathbb{S}^n$. Consider the following one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $\psi_{\lambda}:\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n$, $\lambda >0$:

$\psi_{\lambda}$ is obtained by using the stereographic projection, then dilating by $\lambda$ and then projecting back. $(\psi_{\lambda})_{\lambda >0}$ is a family of conformal diffeomorphisms that weakly converge to the pole when $\lambda \to \infty$.

In essence, the question is whether something like this can happen between manifolds which are not conformally equivalent (with maps which are asymptotically conformal in the sense defined above).

Comment: I assume that by S^n you mean the sphere with the round metric. What happens if you take another metric on M, not conformal to the round metric on N? If in this case the energy of psi_lambda tends to zero then it's a counter example.